# How to use Xpath extractor to extract mutiple fields using SOAP request in Jmeter?

Tags: apache, xpath, jmeter

I imported the webservice and did my first transaction passed. I see the request and reply xml
Now I want to extract ton of field values from the reply xml that I got and need to pass into Request xml. 
For one field I know how to do that. I use Xpath Extractor to extract like this

```
//*[local-name()='Data']/text()`.
```

In the next action, I can just use as `${Data}` which is working fine.
But I need to extract the text content from ton of fields that need to be passed into the  next action.

How to do that using Xpath Extractor?

Answer (score 0):

If your XPath query matches multiple `/Data/text` fields they will be caught as

- TEXT_1=first match
- TEXT_2=second match
- etc.

If you need to combine results from different queries it can be done via pipe sign - `|` like

```
//*[local-name()='Data']/text()` | //*[local-name()='Something else']/text()
```

In this case result will go to the single variable.

Third option is using as many XPath extractors as needed.

See [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for general language reference and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more tips and tricks.